# Resharper generates C++ code in C# project

Tags: c#, c++, resharper, code-generation, intellisense

Concerns ReSharper Ultimate 2015.2 + VS 2015 Pro.

In a WPF project when I try and insert a "#region" in a *.cs-file using the "Surround with" shortcut - Ctrl+K,Ctrl+S, then select "#region" - I get a C++ region like "*#pragma region MyRegion*".
Same applies for inserting with that shortcut try-catch blocks
Then also C++ code is generated like "*catch (const std::exception&)*"

It's the same for all other projects of the same solution.
One C++ project belongs to the solution.

Anybody any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

I already ran "Clear caches" in the RS options menu, to no avail :(

Comment: Does it occur in other projects?

Comment: @citizenmatt Good point. I didn't realize it before, but actually: Yes.
It the same issue for all C#-solutions, most of them not containing any C++ project, strange.

I already re-created the solution from scratch, same thing :(

Also other RS-code generation works well...

Comment: @citizenmatt  Especially the "Surround With" -members seem to be affected...Also *class, try, tryf, foreach, struct* generate C++ code in C#-files. Maybe some RS cache / config is broken. I'll giv a reinstall of RS a try...

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was NOT a ReSharper issue. But a problem with the Visual Studio installation.
I uninstalled VS, removed all VS config and cache folders in the file system, that I could find, removed all "Visual Studio" registry keys. And then reinstalled VS 2015. Now it's okay again.

Comment: How odd. I suspect that Visual Studio had somehow associated .cs files with the C++ text editor. ReSharper will honour this, even if it's weird.